# Is there a TensorFlowServing equivalent for Google Coral Boards?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

**Context**

I've been playing with the [Google Coral USB Accelerator](https://coral.ai/) for a few days, prototyping some solutions based on classic models like MobileNet (official versions from [here](https://coral.ai/models/)) and other custom models (ported to TensorFlow Lite). Also, I'm working specific with Python version of this libraries.

My purpose is to port a solution that I currently have running on a traditional way (CPU + GPU) to a hybrid CPU + Google Coral way, delegating the inferences to my Coral USB stick.

As my solution involves multiple models and concurrency on demand for inferences, I am using [Tensorflow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving) to serve the models in the original deploy. In this way I delegate concurrency handling to TFS.

On the other hand, I have noticed that my device does not seem to support concurrency and apparently mutual exclusion is not covered by the `tflite_runtime.interpreter` class, which I use to make the inference.

**My Question**

Is there an official API at the level of TensorflowLite, Google Coral framework or some community project that can solve my problem, similar to what TFS does?

Otherwise I guess I will be forced to implement some client/server logic based for example in [this](https://github.com/neuralet/neuralet/blob/master/coral-dev-board/mobilenet_ssd_v2/src/client.py) open source project which uses python `multiprocessing.Manager` objects (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager)).

Thanks a lot in advance!